# Formatted partitions from terminal are read only

Tags: usb, 22.04, fstab, automount

I formatted a USB drive (initially mounted as `/dev/sdb1`, vfat 2GB) from terminal using

```
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb1
```

then created mountpoint in `fstab`

```
UUID=DEVICE_UUID    /media/storage    ext4    defaults,noatime    0    0
```

On reboot, USB becomes read only (can't create any file). But when I format the same drive using `Disks` GUI, I can see there is no `sdb1` but only `sdb` with its own UUID. If I write this UUID into `fstab`, the drive becomes writable. What am I doing wrong in the terminal? Shouldn't there be `sdb1` instead of only `sdb`?